# Update all the records in between from NA to the value

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a data table in the below format :

```
id      c1        c2
1       1         NA
1       1         NA
1       1         10 
1       1         NA   
1       1         NA
1       1         10 
1       1         NA
1       1         NA
1       1         11 
1       1         NA   
1       1         NA
1       1         11
2       1         NA
2       1         12 
2       1         NA   
2       1         NA
2       1         12
```

From this data table I would like to update all the NA in between the two values in c2 as below:

```
    id      c1        c2
    1       1         NA
    1       1         NA
    1       1         10 
    1       1         10   
    1       1         10
    1       1         10 
    1       1         NA
    1       1         NA
    1       1         11 
    1       1         11   
    1       1         11
    1       1         11
    2       1         NA
    2       1         12 
    2       1         12   
    2       1         12
    2       1         12
```

Comment: can you clarify this: " I would like to update all the NA in between the two values in c2 as below:"

Comment: I want to make the values of c2 as the same  in between the range start and end of c2

Comment: are there always only 2 of each value initially?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "range start and end of c2"? It seems to me you're randomly changing `NA`s for values from column `c2`. Could you please provide a clear set of rules, or better still, show your attempt at generating the second table.

Comment: `indx <- setDT(df)[!is.na(c2), .(min(.I):max(.I)), by = c2] ; df[indx$V1, c2 := indx$c2]` perhaps

Answer (score 2):

Can do it using a `for` loop and `which()`:

```
df=data.frame(id = c(rep(1,12)),c2 = c(NA,NA,10,NA,NA,10, NA,NA,11,NA,11,NA))
```

Find unique values of c2:

```
vals=unique(df[which(!is.na(df$c2)),'c2'])
```

Loop through unique values and replace observations between their first and last appearance:

```
for(i in vals){
  df[min(which(df$c2==i)):max(which(df$c2==i)),'c2']=i
}
```

Comment: This does not woek if the data frame has two numbers continuioslylike

Comment: Can you give an example, or update your question to show when it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

Besides [David's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46930839/how-to-update-all-the-records-in-between-from-na-to-the-value#comment80811905_46930839) which is working directly with row indices there is another `data.table` approach which uses a *non-equi join*:

```
# coerce to data.table
setDT(DT)[
  # append unique row id
  , rn := .I][
    # non-equi join on row ids
    DT[!is.na(c2), .(rmin = min(rn), rmax = max(rn)), by = c2], 
    on = .(rn >= rmin, rn <= rmax), c2 := i.c2][
      # remove row id column
      , rn := NULL][]
```

> ```
>     id c1 c2
>  1:  1  1 NA
>  2:  1  1 NA
>  3:  1  1 10
>  4:  1  1 10
>  5:  1  1 10
>  6:  1  1 10
>  7:  1  1 NA
>  8:  1  1 NA
>  9:  1  1 11
> 10:  1  1 11
> 11:  1  1 11
> 12:  1  1 11
> 13:  2  1 NA
> 14:  2  1 12
> 15:  2  1 12
> 16:  2  1 12
> 17:  2  1 12
> ```

#### Caveat

The expression

```
DT[!is.na(c2), .(rmin = min(rn), rmax = max(rn)), by = c2]
```

returns the row id ranges for each unique value of `c2`

> ```
>    c2 rmin rmax
> 1: 10    3    6
> 2: 11    9   12
> 3: 12   14   17
> ```

There is an implicit assumption that the row id ranges *do not overlap*. It requires that each "gap" is associated with a unique `c2` value. This affects other solutions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46930839/how-to-update-all-the-records-in-between-from-na-to-the-value#comment80811905_46930839), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46931058/3817004) as well.

#### Improved solution using `rleid()`

The code can be improved to handle cases where the above mentioned assumption is violated.

Using `rleid()`, we can distinguish different gaps even if the have the same `c2` value. For instance, for the second sample data set

```
DT2[!is.na(c2), .(c2 = first(c2), rmin = min(rn), rmax = max(rn)), by = rleid(c2)]
```

> ```
>    rleid c2 rmin rmax
> 1:     1 10    3    6
> 2:     2 11    9   12
> 3:     3 12   14   17
> 4:     4 10   20   23
> ```

The complete code:

```
setDT(DT2)[, rn := .I][
  DT2[!is.na(c2), .(c2 = first(c2), rmin = min(rn), rmax = max(rn)), by = rleid(c2)], 
  on = .(rn >= rmin, rn <= rmax), c2 := i.c2][, rn := NULL][]
```

> ```
>     id c1 c2
>  1:  1  1 NA
>  2:  1  1 NA
>  3:  1  1 10
>  4:  1  1 10
>  5:  1  1 10
>  6:  1  1 10
>  7:  1  1 NA
>  8:  1  1 NA
>  9:  1  1 11
> 10:  1  1 11
> 11:  1  1 11
> 12:  1  1 11
> 13:  2  1 NA
> 14:  2  1 12
> 15:  2  1 12
> 16:  2  1 12
> 17:  2  1 12
> 18:  2  1 NA
> 19:  2  1 NA
> 20:  2  1 10
> 21:  2  1 10
> 22:  2  1 10
> 23:  2  1 10
> 24:  2  1 NA
> 25:  2  1 NA
>     id c1 c2
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("id      c1        c2
1       1         NA
1       1         NA
1       1         10 
1       1         NA   
1       1         NA
1       1         10 
1       1         NA
1       1         NA
1       1         11 
1       1         NA   
1       1         NA
1       1         11
2       1         NA
2       1         12 
2       1         NA   
2       1         NA
2       1         12")
```

Expanded data set (note the repeated appearance of `c2 == 10`):

```
DT2 <- fread("id      c1        c2
1       1         NA
1       1         NA
1       1         10 
1       1         NA   
1       1         NA
1       1         10 
1       1         NA
1       1         NA
1       1         11 
1       1         NA   
1       1         NA
1       1         11
2       1         NA
2       1         12 
2       1         NA   
2       1         NA
2       1         12
2       1         NA
2       1         NA
2       1         10 
2       1         NA   
2       1         NA
2       1         10 
2       1         NA
2       1         NA")
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay (new/edited answer), we can make use of the fact that the desired property of a solution is that filling up should yield the same result as filling down:

```
library(tidyverse)    
df %>% 
mutate(filled_down = c2, filled_up = c2) %>% 
fill(filled_down, .direction="down") %>% 
fill(filled_up, .direction="up") %>% 
mutate(c2 = ifelse(filled_down == filled_up, filled_down, c2)) %>% 
select(-filled_down, -filled_up)
```

Comment: You're right. It seems it's only wanted to replace NA between values that don't change.

Comment: Note my answer as edited should now do what's required.